# Importing downloaded GeoPackage file into QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, geopackage, zip

I have downloaded a zip file with several distribution data of species around the world. I extracted it and now I have just one file (*.gpkg* file).

I am trying to import it in QGIS 3.10 but when I open it, it seems empty. Could you help me?

Comment: If it contains data, dragging it onto your map canvas will display a dialogue which lets you select layers to add.

Comment: Geopackage files have layers. You need to select the specific layer of data you want

Comment: Assuming this geopackage contains layers:
Open Qgis.
press `ctrl + shift + v`.

For "Source", browse to the .gpqg file.

Press "Add".

A new window will show you which layers from the .gpkg file do you want to import.

Pick the ones you want to add to your project, an press "Ok".

Comment: can you provide the download link to the zipped geopackage?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you so much for your answers but I did not solve my problem. I will try to attach you the zip file or the link.

Comment: https://mol.org/datasets/ec694c34-bddd-4111-ba99-926a5f7866e8      You should create an account to get access to the database. If you do not want I can give you my credentials. Then, you should go to "download" and try with one of the files (es. Pholidota)